# Ошибка в PyCharm Failed building wheel for yarl при установке aiogram

Tags: pycharm, aiogram

Всем привет! Проблема в заголовке.

```
(Bot) C:\PycharmProjects\Bot>pip install -U aiogram
Collecting aiogram
  Using cached aiogram-2.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2019.3.9 in c:\python\bot\lib\site-packages (from aiogram) (2020.6.20)
Processing c:\users\grob\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b6\9c\bd\6b99bc6ec9dab11f3756d31fb8506d3ecf07aea58b6201f539\aiohttp-3.6.3-py3-none-any.whl

Collecting Babel>=2.6.0
  Using cached Babel-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in c:\python\bot\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.5.4->aiogram) (3.0.4
)
Collecting yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.5.1.tar.gz (173 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2015.7
  Using cached pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna>=2.0 in c:\python\bot\lib\site-packages (from yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4.0.0,>=3.5.4->aiogr
am) (2.10)
Building wheels for collected packages: yarl, multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\bot\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\python\bot\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\GROB\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\tmpkk7efgaj'
       cwd: C:\Users\GROB\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fvphy8bh\yarl
  Complete output (35 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-
build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\bot\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\python\bot\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\GROB\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\tmphtv9219g'
       cwd: C:\Users\GROB\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fvphy8bh\multidict
  Complete output (40 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-
build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build yarl multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yarl, multidict which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Установка Microsoft Visual C++ не помогает, запускаю установку прямо там в терминале и та же ошибка. У кого-то есть варианты решения данной проблемы?

P.S. При выборе интерпритатора Python версии 3.7 проблемы нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поставить библиотеки:

---

pip install -U yarl==1.4.2

---

pip install wheel

---

Мне помогло с Python версией 3.8.6.